# PHP: PHPStorm with xdebug can't enter "break point" after a condition 'if'

Tags: php, if-statement, phpstorm

I have installed and configured the `PhpStorm 6.0` with `jdk 1.7`.

The debug works correctly but when I put a breakpoint after a condition 'if' without having sentences within '{statement ... }' Does not fit. View image 1.

But when I put the sentence in the conditional 'if' inside '{statement}' if it comes into breakpoint. View image 2.

Why is it that is happening? Should enter any of the two cases?

The images below show what is happening:

In this case is the "problem or error":
[image]

In this case work fine:
[image]

Thank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XDEBUG BUG](http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=842)  Sadly it is marked as "not fixable"